Unable to remove side margin space rmarkdown file
I need to remove the space from the side margin as it is consuming most of the space.
A sample code is provided. The main code gets data from internet.
MainStackoverflow.RMD file will call the ChildStackoverflow.RMD file and generate the final html in loop.
There are two functions in the main code which are used to generate the graphs at run time.
MAIN CODE:
    library('quantmod')
    library('ggplot2')
    getSymbols("AAPL",  from = "2018/01/01",to = Sys.Date(), periodicity = "daily")
    getSymbols("MSFT",  from = "2018/01/01",to = Sys.Date(), periodicity = "daily")
    getSymbols("META",  from = "2018/01/01",to = Sys.Date(), periodicity = "daily")
    getSymbols("ORCL",  from = "2018/01/01",to = Sys.Date(), periodicity = "daily")
    v_lst_cols = c('OPEN','HIGH','LOW','CLOSE','VOLUME','ADJUSTED','DATE')
    df_AAPL <- as.data.frame(AAPL)
    df_AAPL$DATE <- index(AAPL)    
    rownames(df_AAPL) <- NULL
    names(df_AAPL) <- v_lst_cols
    df_AAPL$SYMBOL <- 'AAPL'
    df_MSFT <- as.data.frame(MSFT)
    df_MSFT$DATE <- index(MSFT)    
    rownames(df_MSFT) <- NULL
    names(df_MSFT) <- v_lst_cols
    df_MSFT$SYMBOL <- 'MSFT'
    df_META <- as.data.frame(META)
    df_META$DATE <- index(META)    
    rownames(df_META) <- NULL
    names(df_META) <- v_lst_cols
    df_META$SYMBOL <- 'META'
    df_ORCL <- as.data.frame(ORCL)
    df_ORCL$DATE <- index(ORCL)    
    rownames(df_ORCL) <- NULL
    names(df_ORCL) <- v_lst_cols
    df_ORCL$SYMBOL <- 'ORCL'
    
    df_all <- rbind(df_AAPL, df_MSFT,df_META,df_ORCL)
    df_all <- df_all[, c('SYMBOL','DATE','OPEN','HIGH','LOW','CLOSE','VOLUME','ADJUSTED')]
    names(df_all) <- c('Symbol','Date','Open','High','Low','Close','Volume','Adjusted')
    v_lst_all_symbol = c('AAPL','MSFT','META','ORCL')
    v_glbl_shrt_rpt_prd = 30
    v_glbl_long_rpt_prd = 220
    v_par_list = list()
    for(i in 1:length(v_lst_all_symbol)){
      v_tmp_list = list(Symbol = v_lst_all_symbol[i])
      v_par_list[[i]] =v_tmp_list
    }
    v_max_date = max(df_all$Date)
    p_dt_hdr_fixed_file = data.table(df_all[df_all$Date == v_max_date,])
    #- - - - - - - - 
    func_plot_nyrs_data_test <- function(p_yrs,p_Symbol){
      #print(i_yrs)
      if ( p_yrs == 5) { v_width = "6 month"}
      if ( p_yrs == 2) { v_width = "3 month" }
      print(p_Symbol)
      df_tmp_hist_dat <- df_all %>% dplyr::filter(Symbol == p_Symbol) %>% dplyr::filter(as.Date(Date) > Sys.Date()-p_yrs*365) 
      v_cur_close <- df_tmp_hist_dat$Close[1]
      v_low_min   = min(df_tmp_hist_dat$Low,na.rm = TRUE)
      v_high_max  = max(df_tmp_hist_dat$High, na.rm = TRUE)
      v_def       = round((v_high_max- v_low_min)/20)
      if (v_def == 0) {
        v_def  = round((v_high_max- v_low_min)/20,1)}
      if (v_def == 0) {
        v_def  = round((v_high_max- v_low_min)/20,2)}  
      if (v_def > 0) {
        if (nrow(df_tmp_hist_dat) >= 60) {
          return(ggplot(df_tmp_hist_dat, aes(x = Date, y = Close, group = 1)) + geom_line(data = ) + 
                   scale_x_date(date_labels = "%Y%b",breaks = scales::date_breaks(width = v_width)) + 
                   theme(text = element_text(size = 10),axis.text.x = element_text(face = "bold", color = "#993333",size = 10, angle = 45),
                         axis.text.y = element_text(face = "plain", color = "#993333",size = 9, angle = 0)) + 
                   scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(seq(1,50000,v_def))) + theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = 'grey87'),panel.grid.major.y = element_line(colour = c("chartreuse4","cadetblue4", "brown4","blue1","deeppink"), linetype = 4)) + 
                   labs(subtitle = paste(p_Symbol,p_yrs,'yrs') ))
        }
      } 
    }
    ------
      func_base_make_candle_chart_new_test <- function(p_symbol,p_grph_prd, p_dat = df_all) {
        v_max_date = max(p_dat$Date);vals <- p_dat %>% filter(Symbol == p_symbol & Date > v_max_date-(p_grph_prd)) 
        if (nchar(vals$Date[1]) == 8){
          vals$Date <- as.Date(as.character(vals$Date), '%Y%m%d')
        } else{
          vals$Date <- as.Date(vals$Date) }
        names(vals)[names(vals) == 'Vol'] = 'Volume'
        ts <- xts(vals %>% select(Open, High, Low, Close, Volume),
                  order.by = vals %>% pull(Date))
        candleChart(ts, name = p_symbol, type = "auto", up.col = "green", dn.col = "red", theme = "white", plot = TRUE, TA = c(addVo()))
      }
    library('rmarkdown')
    v_rmd_file = '/path/MainStackoverflow.RMD'
    v_output_file = '/path/Output.html'
    rmarkdown::render(v_rmd_file,output_file = v_output_file_html, output_dir = v_output_dir)

#=========================================================
# **MainStackoveflow.RMD File**

```{r message=FALSE, warning=FALSE}
```
--- 
title: "Test" 
output:
  html_document: 
  css: styles.css
  pdf_document: default
--- 
```{r setup, include=FALSE, echo=FALSE, , message=FALSE, warning=FALSE, out.width= 15 , cache = FALSE}
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)
```
echo("one")
```{r, fig.cap = "Test Graphs", echo = FALSE}
if (1==1){
    kable(p_dt_hdr_fixed_file) %>% kable_styling(bootstrap_options = c("striped", "hover", "condensed"), full_width = T, position = "center", font_size = 11)}
```

```{r, echo=TRUE}  
#print('Test')
#print(paste('after before knit expand --> ', length(v_par_list)))
rmd <- sapply( 
  1:length(v_par_list), 
  function(x) { 
    knit_expand("DetailStackoverflow.RMD", x=x, p_Symbol=v_par_list[[x]]$Symbol)
  } 
) 
rmd <- paste(rmd, collapse = "\n") 
```
```{r results = "asis", echo=FALSE} 
rendered <- knit(text = rmd, quiet = TRUE) 
cat(rendered, sep = "\n") 
```
#===================================================
**DetailStackoverflow.RMD file**
```{r message=TRUE, warning=TRUE}
```
##### {{paste(p_Symbol,'-----' )}}
style="padding:0px;"
```{r, fig.cap = "The caption: ID = {{p_Symbol}}", fig.width=10,fig.fullwidth=TRUE,echo = FALSE, results = 'asis', warning = FALSE , cache = FALSE}
i <- {{x}} 
v_Symbol        = v_par_list[[i]]$Symbol
cat("
<style>
caption {
      color: black;
      font-weight: bold;
      font-size: 1.0em;
    }
</style>
")
#print(v_company)

```
```{r, fig.cap = "Yearly Graphs",fig.width=10,fig.fullwidth=TRUE,fig.height=5, echo = FALSE,fig.align='center', cache = FALSE}
#| column: page
func_plot_nyrs_data_test(2,v_Symbol)
func_base_make_candle_chart_new_test(v_Symbol,v_glbl_shrt_rpt_prd)
```



Quarto
If using quarto one may use the column option. All content for which one wants a wider margin can be put inside fenced divs with the use of the column option. See the documentation for more options.
main.qmd or main.Rmd processed with Quarto

:::{.column-page}

```{r}

 knitr::kable(mtcars[1:6, 1:10])
```

:::


Output:

R Markdown and Knitr
Following this SO answer, one can also use a custom CSS with a reference in the YAML of the main .Rmd file.
custom.css
div.main-container {
  max-width: 1600px !important;
}

main.Rmd
---
title: asd
author: abc
date: "`r format(Sys.time(), '%d %B, %Y')`"
output:
  html_document:
    toc: true
    toc_float: true
    toc_depth: 6
    mathjax: null
    css: custom.css
---


I tried to use the code as suggested. Part of it is : '''```{r message=FALSE, warning=FALSE}
---
title: "Test"
author: "test"
date: "`r format(Sys.time(), '%d %B, %Y')`"
output:
  html_document:
    toc: true
    toc_float: true
    toc_depth: 6
    mathjax: null
---

:::{.column-page}
knitr::kable(
  mtcars[1:6, 1:10]
:::
''' But still there is no change. Can you use the existing code to generate the output as suggested.

For quarto yes. I added a screenshot to demonstrate. I did however incorrectly reference the css file. I changed that to properly reference custom.css rather than doc.css which I had before by mistake.
